# Python Shapely determine if the polygon of interest is touch from Left, Right, Up, or Down directions

Tags: python, geometry, polygon, shapely

[Python Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) is a great library for checking spatial relationships among polygons, and points. I understand it allows checking predicates such as interest/ touch/ contain among polygons. I'm particularly interested in knowing if there's a way to know the specific direction that other polygons touch the initial polygon of interest. For example, in the image provided below, is there a way to know that rectangle 1 touches the rectangle of interest on it's left hand side, rectangle 4 on right hand side, rectangle 2 from the top, and rectangle 3 from bottom. Is there a way to extend below instruction to determine the specific direction?

type(polygon_of_interest.intersection(candidate_polygon_1)) is geometry.LineString

[image]

Comment: You can get a centroid of each polygon and compare coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import box, LineString, Polygon


def touch_direction(touched_poly, touching_poly_list):
    """
    Determine a direction from where polygons in a list of touching polygons 
    touch a certain Shapely Polygon
    
    :param touched_poly:        The Shapely polygon that is touched
    :type touched_poly:         Polygon
    :param touching_poly_list:  A flat list of Shapely Polygons that are known 
                                to touch the `touched_poly` Polygon
    :type touching_poly_list:   list
    :return:                    A dictionary having 4 keys ("top", "bottom", "left", "right") 
                                each having as value a list with the Shapely Polygons that 
                                touch the targeted Polygon (touched_poly) from 
                                a certain spatial direction
    :rtype:                     dict
    """
    
    result = {
        "top":[],
        "bottom": [],
        "left": [],
        "right": []
    }
    # the minx, miny, maxx, maxy bounding box bounds for the touched polygon
    touched_bounds = touched_poly.bounds

    # we create a Polygon that is a bit bigger than the touched polygon bounding box 
    # such we can check if any touching polygon crosses that boundary
    "https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.crosses"
    # feel free to adjust the distance parameter in the following buffer() call,
    # currently distance = 0.1
    touch_bounds_poly_buffered = box(*touched_bounds).buffer(distance=0.1)

    # get the bounding limits for the new enlarged bounding box Polygon
    minx, miny, maxx, maxy = touch_bounds_poly_buffered.bounds

    # and make 4 LineStrings out of them, one for each direction
    left_line = LineString([(minx, miny), (minx, maxy)])
    right_line = LineString([(maxx, miny), (maxx, maxy)])
    top_line = LineString([(minx, maxy), (maxx, maxy)])
    bottom_line = LineString([(minx, miny), (maxx, miny)])

    # iterate over the touching polygons and determine through which line they cross
    # it is possible that the touching polygon will touch from multiple directions 
    # therefore it can be found in more than one list in the result
    for touching_poly in touching_poly_list:
        if touching_poly.crosses(top_line):
            result["top"].append(touching_poly)
        if touching_poly.crosses(bottom_line):
            result["bottom"].append(touching_poly)
        if touching_poly.crosses(left_line):
            result["left"].append(touching_poly)
        if touching_poly.crosses(right_line):
            result["right"].append(touching_poly)

    return result
```

Comment: seems pretty ineffective, but +1 for attempt